# React combo doesnt select proper value

Tags: reactjs

I'm totally new in react and I am trying to create add/edit form with combo box in it. I saved data in database but now when I loaded the form there is no selected value in "bank" combo. Looks like combo gets default value "Select"  and I don't know where is the problem. My .net backend returns proper bank id from database and `company.bankId` also has value.

```
interface IProps {
    closeAddEditCompanyModal: any,
    cancelClick: any,
    saveClick: any,
    isVisible: boolean,
    currentCompany: CompanyModel,
}

interface IState {
    company: CompanyModel;
    validationMessage: string,
    isLoading: boolean,
    activeIndex: number;
    selectedIndex: number;
    banks: Array<BankModel>;
    isVisibleAddEditBankDialog: boolean;
}

handleChangeSelect = (key, e) => {
    const company: CompanyModel = { ...this.state.company};
    company[key] = e.value;
    this.setState({ company: { ...company } });
};

<div style={{ minHeight: '50px' }}>
    <FormControl>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="active-label">Banks</InputLabel>
        <Select 
            name="bankId"
            options={this.state.banks.map( bank => ({ 
                value: bank.bankId, 
                label: bank.bankName 
            }))}
            onChange={(e) => this.handleChangeSelect('bankId', e)}
            value={company && company.bankId ? company.bankId : ''}
        >   
        </Select>
   </FormControl>
```

Comment: Could you tell what package you are using. Might be better if you could add the imports. If you aren't aware of what libraries to be used, i would suggest using material ui or react select. I would also suggest you to use functional component rather than class component

Comment: @Kiran I use react select .
`import Select from 'react-select;'
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';`

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

function App() {
  
  const [companyId, setCompanyId] = useState();

  const letterChange = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    company[data.value] = data.value;
    // you can do here whatever you wish to do
    // setCompanyId(data);
  };

  const banks = [
    { value: "bank1", label: "bank1" },
    { value: "bank2", label: "bank2" },
    { value: "bank3", label: "bank3" },
    { value: "bank4", label: "bank4" },
    { value: "bank5", label: "bank5" },
    { value: "bank6", label: "bank6" },
    { value: "bank7", label: "bank7" },
  ];

  const company = [{
    bank1: { value: "company1", label: "company1" },
    bank2: { value: "company2", label: "company2" },
  }];

  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <Select
          name="bankId"
          options={banks}
          onChange={letterChange}
          value={companyId}
        ></Select>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am still not clear what you are trying to achieve here. But here is a small piece of snippet that might help you.
Couple of things that i would like to point out in your code.

- Inside your onChange handleChangeSelect you are passing a hardcoded value by passing bankId as string. I don't know if thats intentional.
- You don't have to loop through the array inside options. Rather you can just pass the whole array itself.
- This is just a suggestion but if you are already using material ui package you can use the select from material ui itself. This is just to avoid using extra packages unless and until there is a need for it.